# Using proxy without cURL

Tags: php, curl, proxy, socks, stream-socket-client

I have tried to use proxy in php using both the methods. I have socks5 proxies. Which works great when I use `cURL` method. But when I try to use `stream_context_set_default` it doesn't work at all. Is there any way to use proxies ? For example : this proxy `207.174.151.226:45021`doesn't work with `stream_context_set_default` but works with cURL. I don't want to use proxy using  cURL because I need proxy everywhere in my php file. Any help regarding this ? Code :

```
<?php
$default_opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar",
    'proxy'=>"186.34.59.99:10000"
  )
);

$default = stream_context_set_default($default_opts);

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
echo $homepage;


?>
```

This works :

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
$ch = curl_init();

if($ch === false)
{
    die('Failed to create curl object');
}

$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

//proxy details
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '186.34.59.99:10000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post your actual code, including your stream_context_create call

Comment: @Sjon done! added my code.

Comment: Did you try prefixing your proxy-address with `tcp://` as described in the manual?

Comment: Yes. It then says Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.co.uk): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in proxy.php on line 13

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send the URI including the original hostname. You can achieve this by explicitly passing `request_fulluri = true` as part of `$default_opts['http']` as described on http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: Still same result. I have added this parameter.